# MongoDB aggregation with multiple inter-related collections

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collections;

```
users, user_roles, market_managers,  program_markets, programs
```

I can export the data from mongoDB in CSV format and construct relational tables and run the following SQL statement to retrieve the data I need;

```
select u.name, ur.type, pm.code, p.program_name, p.shortnam, p.enddate, p.description
from users u, user_roles ur, market_managers mm, program_markets pm, programs p
where u.roles_0 = ur.id
and ur.type = 'CountryManager' 
and u.id = mm.userid
and pm.programid = mm.programid
and pm.id = mm.marketid
and p.id = pm.programid;
```

How can I achieve the same results by writing native mongo syntax?

Here's a list of collections in scope:

users collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3f59c96e1c20d84e2b5ce5"), 
    "name" : "some_country_manager",
    "roles" : [
        "5b2a8df52b3a6f945d4e85fe"
    ]
}
```

user_roles collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b430f9981f6a7382a24995b"), 
    "type" : "countryManager", 
    "name" : "Country Manager"
}
```

market_managers collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5894bcf60418700b70745fc9"), 
    "programId" : "5862c1d43b1a1b113a8a841f", 
    "marketId" : "5862c1d43b1a1b113a8a84a9", 
    "userId" : "5b3f59c96e1c20d84e2b5ce5"
}
```

program_markets collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b43588689c117241c171e8c"), 
    "code" : "de", 
    "startDate" : "2018-07-09", 
    "endDate" : "2019-07-09"
}
```

programs collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5862c1d43b1a1b113a8a841f"), 
    "name" : "Test Program", 
    "shortname" : "TestP", 
    "status" : "planned", 
    "startDate" : "2018-07-09", 
    "endDate" : "2019-07-09", 
    "description" : "Test Program"
}
```

Comment: Please post your sample collection and the output instead of SQL query

Comment: Just wondering if it is even possible to perform join shown above on MongoDB?

Comment: it will be possible just try to do what is have commented above

Comment: `users, user_roles, programs, market_managers, program_managers` try revising your collection design, since MongoDB is NoSql, no need to have normalized data as we have in RDBMS DB's. Here in the collection list given `users and user_roles` can be clubbed together. Likewise look for merging other collections and please note that the tables in RDBMS world is not equivalent of collections. If your final design still has more collections then use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join the collections

Comment: I have updated the question with sample list of collections.

Comment: I would recommend a single collection `program` with all information in it, if not then we can go for two collections `program` and `user`, having five collections for this simple schema is an incorrect design.

Comment: @HadidAli Can you please post the output you want from the above collections... And put `@` while commenting

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet 
FULLNAME,USER_ROLE,CountryCode,ProgramName,ProgramShortname,ProgramEndDate,ProgramDescription
John Smith,CountryManager,GB,PXYZ,2019-03-25,"some description"

Comment: Please post the expected output in the above question and also please explain which are the common keys (matching keys) in the collections so that it would be easier me to make a aggregate query

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet - It should be fairly obvious what are common keys by looking at the SQL query above.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet - almost there! I realised that I needed to correct some fields in the collections as well removing a collection. Could you re-write the query according to to the updated collection list in the question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation if you have mongodb 3.6 and above

```
Users.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id.id) } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": UserRoles.collection.name,
    "let": { "roles_0": "$roles_0" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$roles_0" ] },
        "type": "CountryManager"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "role"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": MarketManagers.collection.name,
    "let": { "user_id": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$user_id" ] }}},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Programs.collection.name,
        "let": { "programid": "$programid" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$programid" ] }}}
        ],
        "as": "programs"
      }},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": ProgramManagers.collection.name,
        "let": { "marketId": "$marketId" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$marketId" ] }}},
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": Programs.collection.name,
            "let": { "id": "$id" },
            "pipeline": [
              { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$id" ] }}}
            ],
            "as": "programs"
          }}
        ],
        "as": "programManagers"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "marketManagers"
  }}
])
```